# How to show $ \left\| \frac{1}{a-|x|^2} f(x) \right\|_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)} \le C \| f (x)\|_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, inequality

Let $a \in \mathbb C$, $a \neq [0,\infty)$. I want to show that 
$$
\left\| \frac{1}{a-|x|^2} f(x) \right\|_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)} \le C \| f (x)\|_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)},
$$
where $C$ is a positive constant. I tried a Cauchy Schwarz inequality , but it does not work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $a \notin [0,\infty)$, we can find a constant $C >0$ such that $|a - |x|^2| \geq C$: If $a \in (-\infty,0)$, set $C = |a|$, if $a \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}$ set $C = |\Im(a)|$ (where $\Im(a)$ denotes the imaginary part of $a$). Hence there is a $C$ > 0 such that  $$\left|\frac{1}{a-|x|^2}\right| \leq \frac{1}{C}$$
and therefore

$$\left\| \frac{1}{a-|x|^2} f(x) \right\|_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)} \leq \frac{1}{C}\|f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)} $$

Comment: sorry thanks! i did a mistake